# Enemy detection in 3D video games without labeled dataset

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm working on a tool for single-class object detection in video games, which should be able to detect enemies in 3D environments. The main problem is, that I cannot use any labeled dataset. Instead I can use gameplay material and game-engine/human player as source of knowledge. Basically I plan to run training process alongside human/bot player playing the game, and make it try to guess location of enemies for each frame, having game-engine/human player as a feedback loop, judging if it pointed at any distinct object at all, and if this object can be considered as enemy. Trained tool should be able to detect enemy based only on pixels of a single game frame.

I'm having some problems in finding out how to approach this problem. Most resources I found about object detection are focused on more traditional CNNs trained with big labeled datasets. I thought about using Reinforcement Learning, because it somehow seem to fit my assumptions about having consecutive states (gameplay frames in this case) and feedback loop assigning reward, but on the other hand using RL for object detection seems somewhat unnatural to me (but I would love to be proved wrong).

Anyway, I will greatly appreciate suggestions of any keywords, articles or solutions that may be helpful or point me in the right direction. Or maybe I should think of some completely different way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Reinforcement learning can do this directly by learning how to interpret the environment. The original *Doom* game is the *drosophila* of this class of problems.

Comment: Right, I have read some papers on RL agents in Doom, but most of them were about agents that play doom, and I (possibly wrongly) assumed that despite RL seems to be very well suited for playing Doom, it may not be so good for detection. But now it's clear that I should look deeper into it, thanks.

Comment: Well, upon reflection I think that your problem is slightly different than the standard task -- the usual *Doom* task is to avoid death, navigate the map, and kill monsters. If all you care about is Identifying monsters, this is clearly a *part* of the third piece (aiming, ammo conservation, etc being related). I guess you could use "weapon discharge" as your "monster detector," because a trained agent will (almost?) always want to shoot the monster when a monster is detected.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using shooting as a detector too. The problem is it could be quite cumbersome to use. I couldn't just present single frame from game and ask detector to find enemy on it. It would be necessary to drop trained agent into environment and let it find enemies. One thing I thought might be interesting to see is to add some SLAM capabilities to the agent, so it could mark 3D positions of enemies on a map. That map would then serve as an output of detector run.

Comment: Shooting could generate labels for the adjacent frames and then you bootstrap a classifier from there. Not shooting gives the negative class.